# Having confusion in navigating from one view page to another view page in php

Tags: javascript, php

On an alert how to fire sql query and load the same page again, as well as how to navigate from one view page to another view page in php following MVC, without using session.

Comment: Share your code....

Comment: Hello @Rishi Agrawal! We would love to help you solve your problem, but your question is not [minimal, verifiable, and complete](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please consider rewriting your question so that we can help you with your code!